# The selected device specifies an unsupported architecture

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I'm trying to launch an Objective C app built on Xcode5 on Xcode6 beta (Version 6.0 (6A215l)). I get the following message when trying to build for any platform except for iPhone 5s:

**`Xcode cannot run using the selected device.`**

`The selected device specifies an unsupported architecture.`

It's not even obvious how to begin troubleshoting this as I can't get to the point where the console is activated. Any pointers?

Comment: What is iOS version of the iPhone 5S? Is it a device or simulator? What are the architectures you are building against?

Comment: @vladof - iPhone 5s (simulator) is the only one that works without that issue. All of the other simulators give me that issue. I am building against iOS 7.0 or above. I am building against arm64, armv7, and armv7s (which is the default architecture list selected in Xcode6 for this project, at least).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had this myself.

I tried a few things (closing simulator before running, having it open, resetting), but what seemed to fix it was a simple clean, build and then run

If that's not it then I have a couple of other things I did but I don't think they were responsible

Comment: Doing a clean seemed to do the trick, actually. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same issue when the Xcode-> Targets-> General-> Deployment->Devices  selected is  iPad. but I am going to run this project on iPhone.   check your project.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this issue after changing the `Executable file` field in the info tab of my target settings - changing this back to the default `${EXECUTABLE_NAME}` fixed it for me.

Comment: This worked for me.  I had edited the bundle and executable name to match my project renaming.  I forgot what I did, then tried to run my project in the simulator. I found this comment after trying the above cleaning suggestions.  By changing Bundle Name and Executable file back to ${PRODUCT_NAME} and ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} back to those variables instead of the name I entered worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue and no amount of cleaning solved it. I had to remove all Swift files from my project. Then I re-added them, but made sure to unselect the "Add to Target" option in the file add dialog. Finally, manually added them to the "Compile Sources" section of your project's "Build Phases". This did it for me. (Also make sure no Swift files end up in the "Copy Bundle Resources" section of Build Phases).

Answer (score 0):

1. Close simulator if it is opend
2. Press Command + shift + k (or clean the project by selecting product menu item from xcode menu) and then press Command + r (or run the project)...

Answer (score 0):

iPhone3gs-->iPhone4s:armv7

iPhone5/iPhone5c: armv7s

iPhone5s --> iPhone6Plus :arm64

add architecture to BuildSetting -> Architecture

Comment: Welcome to the community. Short answers does help, but having some explanation around it makes it more readable. Just a suggestion.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).